# Temp settings on Whirlpool flat top stove

Tags: stove, temperature

Instead of numbers for low to high settings for the burners on my Whirlpool stove top, I have a line that goes from low to high.  Part of that line is thicker in parts as it goes around the dial.  Does anyone know what the thick parts of the line means?
[image]

Comment: Pic would be nice.

Comment: I added a pic to my original post.  The bold line is right past the low setting and starts again just past the medium and stops before the high setting.

Comment: If we knew the model number, we (or you) could hopefully use Google or Google Images to look at after market decal sets that are sold for when markings get worn, and then we might know if the line thickening was an accident during manufacture, or deliberate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the person laying out the lines was having a bad day.
Seriously, it just looks like the printer on that part was wavering. I don't believe there is any meaning.

Comment: That thought crossed my mind but I was hoping it was something interesting.